# Find most recent occurrence of an event for an individual

Tags: sql, date, pivot, amazon-redshift

My apologies for yet another question about finding the most recent date in an array.

Unfortunately, I have not had any luck finding any other posts that meet my particular needs.

- column 1 is a userid
- column 2 is the type of action that occurred and
- column 3 is the date time stamp that the action occurred at

My goal is to group by user_id and have the most recent for the different action types be their own column.

Example data:

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| user_id | source |  created   |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | QT     | 2020-01-01 |
|       2 | QT     | 2020-01-02 |
|       3 | QT     | 2020-01-01 |
|       1 | QT     | 2020-01-03 |
|       2 | QT     | 2020-01-04 |
|       3 | QT     | 2020-01-05 |
|       1 | AT     | 2020-01-02 |
|       2 | AT     | 2020-01-02 |
|       3 | AT     | 2020-01-03 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

Desired outcome:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| user_id |   max QT   |   Max AT   |
+---------+------------+------------+
|       1 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-02 |
|       2 | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-02 |
|       3 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-03 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

My initial thought was:

````
```select
user_id
,case when source = 'QT' THEN max(created) END as "last_QT"
,case when source = 'AT' THEN max(created) END as "last_AT"
from analytics.all_tx_bars_all 
group by user_id```
````

but that gives me the error:
*Invalid operation: column "source" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function*

When I include "source" into the group by and select like:

````
```select
user_id
,source
,case when source = 'QT' THEN max(created) END as "last_QT"
,case when source = 'AT' THEN max(created) END as "last_AT"
from analytics.all_tx_bars_all 
group by user_id,source```
````

I get something like:

```
+---------+--------+------------+------------+
| user_id | source |   max QT   |   Max AT   |
+---------+--------+------------+------------+
|       1 | QT     | 2020-01-03 |            |
|       2 | QT     | 2020-01-04 |            |
|       3 | QT     | 2020-01-05 |            |
|       1 | AT     |            | 2020-01-02 |
|       2 | AT     |            | 2020-01-02 |
|       3 | AT     |            | 2020-01-03 |
+---------+--------+------------+------------+
```

To add a little more color to my question, I'm using the SQL tool in metabase here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need aggregation:

```
select user_id,
       max(case when source = 'QT' then created end) as last_QT,
       max(case when source = 'AT' then created end) as last_AT
from analytics.all_tx_bars_all 
group by user_id;
```

Note that I have removed `source` from both the `select` and the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running Postgres, as the error message seems to indicate, you can do conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select 
    user_id,
    max(created) filter(where source = 'QT') max_qt,
    max(created) filter(where source = 'AT') max_at
from analytics.all_tx_bars_all
group by user_id
```

If your database does not support the `filter` syntax, then we can fallback on `case` expressions:

```
select 
    user_id,
    max(case when source = 'QT' then created end) max_qt,
    max(case when source = 'AT' then created end) max_at
from analytics.all_tx_bars_all
group by user_id
```

Comment: thank you for your quick reply!
Unfortunately that gives me the following error:
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "(" Position: 168;

to add a little more color to my question, I'm using the SQL tool in metabase here

Comment: @TobiahAdam: I updated my answer with a solution that does not use the `filter` syntax.