# Adding boolean column to check whether entry is most recent of their attributes in Postgres SQL table?

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql

Simplified Postgres table looks like this:

```
date        attribute
2002-04-14  C
2001-12-07  A
1990-12-19  A
1990-12-20  B
1991-01-29  A
1991-07-01  C
1990-07-25  B
1999-05-13  B
1990-09-25  A
```

We need to add a boolean column checking whether the `date` is the most recent of entries of `attribute`. The `desired_col` in the table:

```
date        attribute   desired_col
2002-04-14  C           TRUE
2001-12-07  A           TRUE
1990-12-19  A           FALSE
1990-12-20  B           FALSE
1991-01-29  A           FALSE
1991-07-01  C           FALSE
1990-07-25  B           FALSE
1999-05-13  B           TRUE
1990-09-25  A           FALSE
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62566392/4107349) is the closest thing I can find, but makes a new table, but I only want a column.

Someone knowledgeable has suggested [creating a trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html), but I don't understand these or their relevance.

If it helps, we could do this in pandas with `df['desired_col'] = (df.groupby('attribute')['date'].transform('max') == df['date'])`. How can we do this in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve this in a postgresql query using window functions eg

```
SELECT
    df.date,
    df.attribute,
    df.date = MAX(df.date) OVER (PARTITION BY df.attribute) as desired_col
FROM
    df;
```

| date | attribute | desired_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990-09-25 | A | false |
| 2001-12-07 | A | true |
| 1990-12-19 | A | false |
| 1991-01-29 | A | false |
| 1990-07-25 | B | false |
| 1999-05-13 | B | true |
| 1990-12-20 | B | false |
| 2002-04-14 | C | true |
| 1991-07-01 | C | false |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ASDFh5YzjuTDLF1xEuzK6/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

### Edit 1

If you would like to modify the existing table, then you may add the `desired_column` as a boolean column with a default value of `false` and running an update as shown below:

**Query #1**

```
ALTER TABLE df
ADD desired_column bool DEFAULT FALSE;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM df;
```

| date | attribute | desired_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2002-04-14T00:00:00.000Z | C | false |
| 2001-12-07T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |
| 1990-12-19T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |
| 1990-12-20T00:00:00.000Z | B | false |
| 1991-01-29T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |
| 1991-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | C | false |
| 1990-07-25T00:00:00.000Z | B | false |
| 1999-05-13T00:00:00.000Z | B | false |
| 1990-09-25T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |

---

**Query #3**

```
UPDATE df 
SET
    desired_column = true
FROM (
    SELECT df2.attribute, MAX(df2.date) as max_date
    FROM df as df2
    GROUP BY df2.attribute
) df3 
WHERE  df.attribute = df3.attribute AND
       df.date = df3.max_date;
```

There are no results to be displayed.

---

**Query #4**

```
SELECT * FROM df;
```

| date | attribute | desired_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1990-12-19T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |
| 1990-12-20T00:00:00.000Z | B | false |
| 1991-01-29T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |
| 1991-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | C | false |
| 1990-07-25T00:00:00.000Z | B | false |
| 1990-09-25T00:00:00.000Z | A | false |
| 2002-04-14T00:00:00.000Z | C | true |
| 2001-12-07T00:00:00.000Z | A | true |
| 1999-05-13T00:00:00.000Z | B | true |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ASDFh5YzjuTDLF1xEuzK6/1)

It should be noted that maintaining this column performance wise may be expensive as it could mean that adding a new record would trigger and update (which can be implemented) but would not be ideal if you do need the performance of a materialized view. It may be more efficient to have your table and when results for this column is desired then you run a query or you query a view that references the table eg.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vw_df AS 
SELECT
    df.date::text,
    df.attribute,
    df.date = MAX(df.date) OVER (PARTITION BY df.attribute) as desired_col
FROM
    df
ORDER BY 
    df.date DESC,
    df.attribute;
```

[View working demo db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ASDFh5YzjuTDLF1xEuzK6/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Almost perfect! How can we add `desired_col` to the existing table?

Comment: @ChrisDixon I've updated the answer with a few suggestions and considerations for performance. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what table Query #2 is on? From the initial query saved as a new table somewhere? And where do df2 and df3 come from in Query #3?

Comment: As seen in the fiddle we originally have the table with 2 columns `df`. Query #2 modifies that initial table to add a new column with a default value. In query #3 `df2` is just an alias for the same table `df` done for readability only (not required) when referencing it's fields. `df3` is the alias for the subquery created that gets the max date for each attribute which is used to filter the records which will be updated in the initial table `df`